# I Need to Degarble a Text File

Tags: data-recovery, text-editing

Here's my dilemma:
I'm [NaNoWriMoing](http://nanowrimo.org/) in a text file backed up with Dropbox, and so I was offline for about 5 hrs and working on my novel. Unfortunately, the computer overheated/ran out of battery/whatever and it did a hard kill (really need to move off these $300 netbooks). So now I have a garbled novel. It's not large--only about 30kb--but would still take a while to rewrite.

What's the best utility/method to try to recover a garbled text file?

(OS doesn't matter. I have access to all 3 major OSs on Saturday. Also, if relevant, I was using FocusWriter when the computer killed itself.)

Comment: open it via a Notepad++ / HexEditor and try to grab the text ? `PS: All the best!`

Comment: Would that work? I'm writing in Unicode.

Comment: Unicode ? Damn. Worth a shot though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the features of Dropbox is that you can rollback to previous versions, or undelete deleted files.  Go to the Dropbox website, find your folder and choose More Actions > Previous Versions.

You can also look in the local Dropbox cache folder:

```
%appdata%\dropbox\cache
```

Comment: Did that. I love Dropbox. Too bad I synced a whole 5 hours ago :-(.

Comment: @digitxp: Try looking in the local cache then.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Wasn't there. I ended up having to rewrite it. Since I already knew what I was going to write, I hit the 2k mark anyway.